# php multidimensional array recursively into an object

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that i would like to create into an object so I can then output both as xml and json.

I am having difficulty getting my head around how to do this recursively. I have looked at many multidimensional posts I can find on here but am still stuck.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Dataset
{
    public $name;
    public $attr = array();
    public $children = array();

    function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function addAttr($attr){
        $this->attr[] = $attr;
    }

    function addChildren($children){
        $this->children[] = $children;
    }
}



$jazzy = Array(
    name => 'aaa',
    attr => Array(
        id => 123
    ),
    children => Array(
        Array(
            name => 'name',
            attr => Array(),
            children => Array(
                'www'
            ),
        ),
        Array(
            name => 'websites',
            attr => Array(),
            children => Array(
                Array(
                    name => 'website',
                    attr => Array(
                        id => 456,
                        class => 'boom'

                    ),
                    children => Array(
                        Array(
                            name => 'url',
                            attr => Array(),
                            children => Array(
                                'www.test.com'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                Array(
                    name => 'website',
                    attr => Array(
                        id => 123,
                        class => "boom"
                    ),
                    children => Array(
                        Array(
                            name => 'url',
                            attr => Array(),
                            children => Array(
                                'www.example.com'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I am looking to create this output

```
<aaa id="123">
    <name>www</name>
    <websites>
        <website id='456' class="boom">
            <url>www.test.com</url>
        </website>
        <website id='123 class="boom">
            <url>www.example.com</url>
        </website>
    </websites>
</aaa>
```

My code

```
function arrayToDataset($array, $node){

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $name = $array['name'];
        $attr = $array['attr'];
        $children = $array['children'];

        if($key == "name"){
            $name = $value;
            $node->addName($name);
        }
        elseif($key == "attr"){
            $attr = $value;

        $node->addAttr($attr);
        }

        elseif($key == "children")
        {
            $children = $value;
            $newNode = new Dataset();

            foreach($children as $k => $v)
            {
                $newNode = $node->addChildren($v);
            }
            return arrayToDataset($children, $newNode);
        }
    }
}

$node = new Dataset();
$thing = arrayToDataset($jazzy, $node);
print_r($thing);
```

Comment: take a look at the [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function.

Comment: * this function only visits leaf nodes *

Comment: the $jazzy array isn't properly formatted - don't know iif this is a copy of your code, but the keys should be quoted. It would be easier to help if we could copy/paste the code...

Comment: The data is inconsistent also - sometimes children is an array or arrays (nodes) and sometimes an array of strings.

Comment: Where, exactly are you stuck?  You've shown what your desired output is, but not your current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a way to parse the data into your DataSet object, which you could then use to output in some other format like xml or json. There may be easier ways to do that though...

```
class Dataset
{
    public $name;
    public $attr = array();
    public $children = array();
    public $url = array();

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function addAttr($attr, $value)
    {
        $this->attr[$attr] = $value;
    }

    function addChild(DataSet $child)
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

    function addUrl($url) {
        $this->url[] = $url;
    }

    static function makeNode($array)
    {
        // $array needs to have the required elements
        $node = new DataSet($array['name']);
        if (isset($array['attr'])) {
            foreach ($array['attr'] as $k => $v) {
                if (is_scalar($v)) {
                    $node->addAttr($k, $v);
                }
            }
        }
        if (isset($array['children']) && is_array($array['children'])) {
            foreach ($array['children'] as $c) {
                if(is_scalar($c)) {
                    $node->addUrl($c);
                } else {
                    $node->addChild(self::makeNode($c));
                }
            }
        }
        return $node;
    }

}

print_r(Dataset::makeNode($jazzy));
```